# How to get the number of task for a certain period in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

To monitoring the volume of specific task on Google App Engine. It's necessary to measure how the may task is queued and ran for a certain period of time. The default monitoring information in Stackdrive is not based on the number of tasks but they are based on the average running time. 
If there are any monitoring console menu or simple way to count the number of tasks, it will be very helpful to optimize queueing and CRON scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the getStats feature of the Task Queue REST API (v1) is not yet supported in [Cloud Tasks API (v2)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/rest/migrating-from-restapi-v1#using_getstats). As a workaround, you can programmatically use the [QueueStatistics](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueStatistics) class available in the App Engine SDK. You may try using the methods “getNumTasks”, “getExecutedLastMinute”, “getRequestsInFlight” and “getEnforcedRate” in order to get an approximation of how tasks are being executed.

Comment: It will be definitely useful to me, I will add that class to view the statics. I do not know why Google is so lazy to provide these statistics.